# Exit code 139 (cannot get the current position)

Tags: omnet++, veins, inet

I have been migrating my routing protocol code from INET 3 to INET 4 and I got An error code 139 and after running the debug mode ,the debug pointer referred to the command :

`Coord senderPos=mobility->getCurrentPosition();`

Note: I am using `veins-inet Mobility` in veins-5.1-i2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=error+code+139 -- you searched those already?

Answer (score 2):

Try including the below-mentioned code lines in your application's .h file.

```
#include "veins_inet/veins_inet.h"
#include "veins_inet/VeinsInetMobility.h"

veins::VeinsInetMobility* mobility;
veins::TraCICommandInterface* traci;
veins::TraCICommandInterface::Vehicle* traciVehicle;
```

And, the below-mentioned code lines in your application's .cc file.

```
mobility = veins::VeinsInetMobilityAccess().get(getParentModule());
traci = mobility->getCommandInterface();
traciVehicle = mobility->getVehicleCommandInterface();
```

Comment: thanks for your reply . I have checked my code and realized that the command :   mobility = check_and_cast<IMobility *>(host->getSubmodule("mobility")); is missing . may be I deleted it by mistake.